# Можно ли убрать централизацию маркеров вокруг кластера во время его раскрытия? Folium

Tags: python, folium

Я формирую метки и создаю группу кластеров, после чего всё это наношу на карту. Если на карте раскрыть кластер, то все метки будут вокруг кластера, теряя детализацию точного местонахождения. Можно ли с этим как-то бороться?

Программе подаются координаты зданий города.

Код:

```
# Map
graph_map = folium.Map(location=[48.700001, 44.516666], 
                       zoom_start = 13, 
                       preference_canvas = True)

# Загрузка датасета
data = pd.read_csv('distribution.csv')
data.head()

# Широта/долгота из файла
latitude = data['latitude'].values
longitude = data['longitude'].values

marker_cluster = FastMarkerCluster(data = [], name = 'cluster')

for lat, lon in zip(latitude, longitude):
    marker = folium.CircleMarker([lat, lon],
                                 fill_color = 'orange',
                                 color = "gray",
                                 fill_opacity = 0.9)
    marker_cluster.add_child(marker)

marker_cluster.add_to(graph_map)

graph_map.save("mymap.html")
webbrowser.open("mymap.html")
```

Пример данных в distribution.csv

```
id,age,gender,latitude,longitude
0,0,woman,48.75082196433389,44.50099524093952
1,0,woman,48.751371525873964,44.50047526843865
2,0,woman,48.75031299654723,44.50211795340297
3,0,woman,48.750585444193284,44.50071324099455
4,0,woman,48.75167175711843,44.500434108055316
5,0,woman,48.75115619908235,44.501843416313804
6,0,woman,48.74987127530585,44.50166013064322
7,0,woman,48.75100339498215,44.50084910753308
8,0,woman,48.75109811157287,44.50145643382246
9,0,woman,48.751650758169,44.50145589458553
10,0,woman,48.750560445232914,44.50154319543671
```

Comment: для начала можно конкретизировать вопрос, указав код и пример данных, достаточных для воспроизведения проблемы. в противном случае ваш вопрос нарушает правила сайта.

Comment: ну вы бы хоть пример distribution.csv еще дали, если он не секретный, конечно.

Comment: ну с данными разобрались. теперь непонятно, что вас не устраивает  - кластер замечательно раскрывается с изменением масштаба карты, и координаты, как  могу судить, при наведении на маркеры вполне себе точные.

Comment: Изменяя масштаб карты не все кластеры раскрываются (меток на карте чуть больше 1000000), так как в конкретном месте находится большое количество меток. Если самим раскрыть кластер путём нажатия по нему, то метки будут идти вокруг него, то есть строить круги или спирали, но не показывая точного местоположения.

Comment: я боюсь, что эту проблему програмно не решить -  масштаб карты конечен, фолиуму "не хватает" места для точного размещения маркеров